# Is There Any Way to Bypass Model::created() Event on Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-5.7

**`UserModel.php`**

In my user model there is `created` event which is called every time when new user is created using `User::Save()`

```
 protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    self::created(function (User $user) {
        // Some operation goes here
    });
}
```

**Now what i want is for some reason i don't want to call that `created` when i create new user record.**

Is there any way to bypass `createdEvent` ??

Answer (score 1):

Check this `withoutEvent` method on model included in recent version of Laravel.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/d4f89f9ca33c70672b0c5eeb0f9523a557841e69/CHANGELOG-5.7.md#v5726-2019-02-12